# My function is not calling properly after I close a file?

Tags: python, list, function

I am in an intro class and I've been looking for an answer for hours but I can't find one. My assignment is to use a txt. file and the list in it as an address book and whenever I call my menu() function after closing the file it doesn't run right it just is blank, I've printed "H" in places throughout the program to find where the logic error is and I've singled it down to after I close the file on line 47, If anybody would be able to help me it would be greatly appreciated and I'm a noob so roast my code as much as you like.[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC9kL.png)

Comment: Screenshots of code are not acceptable on Stack Overflow. Please post your code as text!

Answer (score 0):

How are you opening the file right now? You may be opening the file in a write mode that overwrites prior content, if so I would suggest using `open` in the following form:

```
with open("demofile.txt", "r") as file:
   # Do things with file such as reading the lines
   lines = file.readlines()
...
```

This way the file will be open in read-only mode

Answer (score 0):

Your code while open the file may throw some error and thus ending the `try` statement. Try using `with` statement or raise the error on `except` to track where's the error.